# Why is this there a difference in these two methods of vector addition?

Tags: c++

I have written two methods to add multiple vectors together in c++. The input arguments are multiple vectors.

**Method 1: The add simple method**

This method contains an add1 function that is called recursively and adds two vectors by using a loop until the tail of arguments is added together. The result of each vector addition stored in a temporary vector.

A part of this method contains the add function code:

```
template<typename V, typename T>
std::vector<V> function(const std::vector<V>& left1, const std::vector<T>& right1)
{
    std::vector<double> temp(left1.size());
    for (int i=0; i<(int)left1.size(); i++)
        temp1[i] = left1[i] + right1[i];
    return temp1;
}
```

This part takes all the vectors as input argument and returns recursively the above function:

```
template<typename V, typename...T>
std::vector<V> add_vectors_simple(const std::vector<V>& head, const T&... tail)
    {
        return function(head, add_vectors_simple(tail...));
    }
```

**Method 2:**

In this method first a function adds all the elements [i1, i2, i3, .... , in] together recursively, but only for one index. So iteration variable i is also an input parameter of the function. In order to return the final sum vector for each index of the vector the function is called. This code is the function that is called for each index:

```
template<typename V, typename ... T>
std::vector<V> add_vectors_singleloop(
    const std::vector<V>& first, const T&... rest)
{
    std::vector<V> result_vec(first.size());
    std:: vector size_vec = (int)(first.size());
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size_vec ; i++)
    {   
        result_vec[i] = add_elems(i, first, rest...);
    }
    return result_vec;
}
```

The first methods takes longer than the second one. I suspect that is, because each recursive step, a temporary vector needs to be made. But I'm not really sure about that and what is really the cause of it.

Could I please get some feedback on this?

Comment: What is the cause of what?

Comment: *The first methods takes longer than the second one.* -- A question concerning length of time a certain operation or function takes should be accompanied by 1) compiler used, 2) settings used to compile the program, i.e. optimizations, 3) a [mcve] demonstrating the test code.

Comment: I think your suspicions are correct. method 1 creates N temporary vectors, method 2 only creates the result vector. Seems clear enough.

Comment: To expand on @M.A's suggestion: `template<typename T, typename... Rest> std::vector<T> add_vectors(std::vector<T> result, const Rest & rest...) { std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), rest.begin(), result.begin(), std::plus<>{})...; return result; )`

Comment: did you change names when posting here? Where is the definition of `add1` ?

Comment: This could be a nice chance to discover tools called "profilers", which are precisely there to tell you what takes time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes allocating memory is slow.

Here is a more efficient solution:

```
template<class T0, class...Ts>
std::vector<T0>& increment( std::vector<T>& V0, std::vector<Ts> const&... Vs){
  for( T0& e:V0 ){
    auto i=std::addressof(e)-V0.data();
    (e+= ... +=Vs[i]); // binary left fold
  }
  return V0;
}
template<class T0, class...Ts>
std::vector<T0> add( std::vector<T> V0, std::vector<Ts> const&.. Vs){
  increment(V0, Vs...);
  return std::move(V0);
}
```

this does 0 recursion and avoids allocating more than 1 buffer (and sometimes 0!).

The advantage of doing it buffier-wise instead of element-wisr is the possibility of vectorizing the addition and cache coherency when you have many large vectors.  Even there, a `+=` approach can avoid excess memory allocarions.

So I'd write:

```
template<class T0, class T1>
std::vector<T0>& increment( std::vector<T>& V0, std::vector<T1> const& V1){
  for( T0& e:V0 ){
    auto i=std::addressof(e)-V0.data();
    e+= V1[i];
  }
  return V0;
}
template<class T0, class...Ts>
std::vector<T0>& increment( std::vector<T>& V0, std::vector<Ts> const&... Vs){
  ((void)increment(V0, Vs), ...);
  return V0;
}
```

to add efficiently that way.

Then work to make the two-argument increment more efficient.